# Перехват SOAP сообщения в Веб сервисе

Tags: java, soap, веб-служба

Я создал веб сервис в джава и предоставил один метод для работы. После я развернул этот веб сервис на сервере. Далее я создаю клиента, где добавляю необходимые артефакты (которые были сгенерированы командой wsimport на основе wdsl файла) и использую здесь этот метод с веб сервиса. Всё работает отлично. 
Я тут вообще не имел дело с soap сообщениями, всё генерировалось автоматически без моего участия.

У меня стоит задача, преобразование пользовательского soap сообщения в валидное soap сообщение для моего веб сервиса и ответ обратно преобразовать в пользовательский soap. Я создал XSLT описывающий преобразование. Для работы всё есть.

Собственно такой вопрос, как мне перехватить пользовательское SOAP сообщение и где это необходимо сделать, чтобы преобразовать в валидное soap? И как потом отослать ответ? Просто я не понимаю, где делается преобразование этого запроса, где необходимо использовать методы для преобразования этого сообщения. 
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не ясна суть решаемой задачи. С одной стороны, Вы говорите о том, что "*Всё работает отлично*", но при этом "*пользовательское SOAP сообщение*" почему-то не является валидным `SOAP`.

Касательно вопроса. Вы можете перехватить управление во время отправки/получения `SOAP`-сообщения с помощью обработчиков, и получить доступ к сообщению, представленному в виде `DOM`-структуры. Для клиента веб-сервиса это делается так. Объявляем обработчик:

```
public class TestClientHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

  public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
    return null;
  }

  public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
    SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();

    Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) smc.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
    try {
        if (outboundProperty) {//если исходящее

        } else {//если входящее

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
    return true;
  }

  public void close(MessageContext context) {
  }
}
```

При создании экземпляра клиента веб-сервиса, добавляем наш обработчик:

```
    List<Handler> list = new ArrayList<Handler>();
    list.add(new TestClientHandler());
    BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) port;
    bp.getBinding().setHandlerChain(list);
```

Здесь `port` - это ваш клиент веб-сервиса.

На стороне сервера принцип действия схожий, но обработчик добавляется по-другому. В `Java`-класс, реализующий веб-сервис, следует добавить аннотацию `@HandlerChain`:

```
@WebService(name = "MyService")
@HandlerChain(file = "ws-handler.xml")
public class MyService {...
```

Следует создать файл `ws-handler.xml` с таким содержимым:

```
<handler-chain>
    <handler>
        <handler-name>WS Handler</handler-name>
        <handler-class>my.package.TestClientHandler</handler-class>
    </handler>
</handler-chain>
```

Файл `ws-handler.xml` может находится, например, в том же пакете, где и скомпилированный класс веб-сервиса, т.е. - "рядом" с ним.

Получив доступ к `DOM`-структуре сообщения, например, обратившись к методам `message.getSOAPBody()` и `message.getSOAPHeader()`, Вы можете осуществлять любые модификации сообщения. Работа с `DOM` не всегда проста и понятна, придётся разбираться с этим отдельно, но это уже выходит за рамки заданного вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо,  да действительно разобрался и использовал SOAPHandler. Я вот именно не знал про такой обработчик. А теперь все легко делается.